# Gitにてある特定ユーザーのコミットを除いてmasterブランチにマージする方法について

Tags: git

git merge の「squash」オプションにて、masterブランチに一括コミットしているのですが、
このコミットにある特定のauthorのみを取り除いてコミットを行いたいのですが、
可能でしょうか。

Comment: 特定ユーザーを除いてコミットしなおすのは `git filter-branch` でできるようなので、これを使えば一括でどうにかできるかも・・・？ https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples

Comment: どういう状況で特定のauthorを排除したいのだろうか。契約違反とかで彼のコードを破棄しないといけないとか....。う〜ん。

Comment: ありがとうございます、filter-branchの「To remove commits authored by "Darl McBribe" from the history:」が解決策になりました。

Answer (score 1):

ブランチがsome_branchだとすると

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git rev-list --reverse --author='^(?!Taro Tanaka).*$' --perl-regexp master..some_branch | xargs git cherry-pick
```

してからcherry-pickのマージコンフリクトを解消して、

```
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

といったん戻した上で、

```
$ git merge --squash @@{1}
```

みたいな感じでいけると思います。authorはフルネームで指定してね。

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i` を用いると、 rebase の際に、それぞれのコミットを

- 単純にコミットして適用するか
- 直前のコミットに squash するか
- そもそも適用しないのか

を選ぶことができ、また、その適用の順番も自分で変更することができます。

特定の author のコミットがどれかは自分で見つけなければならないですがこれが一番やりたいことに近いのではないかと思っています。